# Implementing String replacement function

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to implement string replacement function however I was able to get to do with character replace(code below). For the string replacement I looked up for Microsoft reference source which has below comment. Although I looked up for the stringbuilder code I couldn't understand it well and I am getting lost.

---

This post was created to find out the implementation of the replacement function and not blindly using string.replace(). It's an interview question to implement the replace function.

This method contains the same functionality as StringBuilder Replace. The only difference is that a new String has to be allocated since Strings are immutable

This is what I had for char replacement

```
public string StringReplaceUtil(string str, char find, char replace)
{
    char[] ch = new char[str.Length];
    int j=0;
    ch = str.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++)
    {
        if (ch[i] == find)
            ch[j] = replace;
        else
            ch[j] = ch[i];
        j++;
    }
    return new string(ch).Substring(0,j);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The bug in your code is that you don't need a separate j index, just use i all the time. Although as others have pointed out - don't do this anyway.

```
char[] ch = str.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < ch.Length; i++)
{
    if (ch[i] == find)
        ch[i] = replace;
}
```

you need the more complex code if you are replacing with a string rather than a character

Comment: @Kar you can ask the question but make it clear that you are doing it as an excercize. IT wasnt clear that you knew there was already a function that did exactly waht you want, people were just saying 'why not use the exisitng function'

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are not using the string.replace() function. This will do exactely what you are trying to do without implementing any new code.

```
string line = "This is a test string"
string find = "a"
string replace = "an awesome"

console.write(line.replace(find, replace))
```

returns:

```
"This is an awesome test string"
```